# Como inserir Entidades, relacionadas á outras ja existentes, no EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

No caso supondo uma entidade "EntidadeA" que referencia uma entidade "EntidadeB", desejo salvar a mesma, porém  referenciando uma entidade B ja existente ex:

```
EntidadeA a = new EntidadeA();
EntidadeB b = new EntidadeB();
b.Id = 5;// id de entidade existente no banco
a.EntidadeB = b;
context.EntidadesA.Add(a);
context.SaveChanges();
//porém neste caso o framework cria uma nova entidade para b,
//o real objetivo é referenciar uma entidade ja persistida com o id 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternativamente, você pode selecionar todas as entidades desejadas através de um contexto e fazer a associação. Por exemplo:

```
var minhasEntidades = contexto.EntidadesB.Where(e => e.Tipo == algumTipo).ToList();
var a = new EntidadeA {
    EntidadesB = minhasEntidades
};

contexto.EntidadesA.Add(a);
contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Há poucas situações em que `Attach` é recomendado, como por exemplo se o registro certamente não estar mapeado pelo contexto naquele momento.

Comment: e se no caso eu tiver n relações em EntidadeA, como EntidadeB, C, D, E, ... e quiser carrega-las sem precisar conhece-las

Comment: Qual é a diferença de Where e Attach ?, porque simplesmente setar a identidade não funciona ?

Comment: `Attach` você está dizendo ao contexto que o registro já existe e ele que ele, contexto, deve aceitar esse objeto como válido. Particularmente acho essa abordagem muito perigosa. No caso do `Where`, você está fazendo de fato uma seleção em banco e pedindo ao contexto para monitorar os objetos pra você, por isso é uma abordagem muito mais segura.

Comment: Agora, quanto a "não precisar conhecer as entidades", não entendi o motivo pelo qual você precisa disso.

Answer (score 2):

Faça deste MODO

```
EntidadeA a = new EntidadeA();
EntidadeB b = new EntidadeB();
b.Id = 5;// id de entidade existente no banco
a.EntidadeB = b;

context.EntidadeB.Attach(a.EntidadeB);

context.EntidadesA.Add(a);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: e se tiverem várias entidades relacionadas  B, C, D,... tem alguma maneira de buscar dotas sem ser atacando uma por uma, por exemplo atcando a A direto ?

Comment: Se tiver várias você terá que fazer um foreach(EntidadeB oEntidadeB in a.EntidadeB) { }